# using Visual force Page How to Create a Custom Calendar For individual users

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, permission-sets

in our salesforce once click HOME Tab, showing Calendar button in Left side panel, like that i need to create a Custom Calendar link in left side Panel... how to achive the Solution can ypu please check and Update me

Thank u       Please check the below Screen shot..

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check the following articles -
[Creating custom links](http://salesforcearticle.com/how-to-create-custom-links-in-salesforce-home-page/)

[How do I get custom links on the home page to open in a new window?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005690&type=1)

> If you are looking for a custom calendar solution then use
>   fullcalendar.js in the Visualforce page. That's how you can display all the events in the calendar.

- [Full Calander Example](https://fullcalendar.io/)
- [Salesforce Implementation](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/3c9ad1294b1466d7b910)

Comment: its OK... but i need to create a Custom Calendar screen... For Example: in Custom link i select UserCalendar_1--> That particular calendar information only display...
Second time i choose UserCalendar_2 --> That time another user Calendar information shown how...
But Admin Views all Users Calendars infromation...

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it helps!!